# "They forbade her to go up onto her roof." VS "They forbade her going up onto her roof."

Tags: grammar

**They forbade her to go up onto her roof.**

**They forbade her going up onto her roof.**

I looked **"forbid"** up, and dictionaries say that **"forbid**" can be followed by **"to"** or **"gerund"**, along with the example sentences. But if forbidding is about a person's doing something, interestingly, all example sentences are shown with infinitive.

And this confuses me, because it may be simply a coincidence or it may be wrong to use gerund in that case. So I want to make sure whether we can say **"They forbade her going up ......"?** OR would that be wrong grammatically?

Comment: I think when you see "forbade [gerund]" constructions it will be a general prohibition not in respect to a particular person, in which latter case you'd find "forbade [someone] to ..."  "The sign forbade parking." vs "The hospital forbade visitors to park in certain spots."

Comment: The infinitive is [***far more common*** after "forbidden"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=were+forbidden+to%2Cwere+forbidden+from&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) than ***from + gerund*** - which latter form has only really started to gain any traction at all in very recent decades. Offhand I can't think of a context where the gerund might actually be completely non-idiomatic, but that's much more likely than there being a context where the *infinitive* is non-idiomatic. So stick with the infinitive and you shouldn't go far wrong.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, So, based on your comments, there are two versions. 1- The infinitive version 2-"from+gerund" version. And there seems to be no instance of "forbid someone doing something"(without "from" and without "to"). So in that case "They forbade her going up onto her roof." would be non-idiomatic, wouldn't it?

Comment: NO! I don't know why you think "They forbade her going up onto her roof" is invalid, but you're mistaken. You should have discovered from dictionaries that ***to forbid*** can take either a ***noun*** or an ***infinitive***. So "They forbid smoking here" uses tthe gerund "smoking" as a noun, same as "They forbid alcohol here". And it's *still* a gerund in "They forbid you smoking here", because the gerund "smoking" can have an associated "subject" *(**you**)*. That's the same as your roof example. "They forbid you from smoking here" is just an alternative featuring the *optional* preposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They forbade her to go up onto her roof.
That is a to-infinitive showing what they did. But it does not imply she had done that.

Also,there is: to forbid someone **from doing something**.

- She was forbidden from going up on the roof.
- They forbade her going up onto her roof.
  This one and the *from*  one implies she was or had been going up there and they are now forbidding that.

Ludwig.guru [you have to sign up so there is not point in posting the actual link, but it's: app.ludwig.guru]

The phrase "forbid from" is correct and usable in written English.
It is commonly used in sentences when describing actions or things that are prohibited or not allowed by someone or something else. Some examples of how it can be used are:

- The school forbids students from bringing their phones to class.
- The company's policy forbids employees from discussing sensitive information with outsiders.
- The doctor forbids the patient from eating any dairy products due to their lactose intolerance.     - The sign forbids visitors from feeding the animals at the zoo.
- The law forbids citizens from owning certain types of weapons.
- The parents forbade their children from watching TV until they finished their homework.

In all of these examples, "forbid from" is used to express a restriction or prohibition on an action or behavior. It can also be used in the negative form, such as "not allowed from," to convey a similar meaning.

Comment: I don't think being *forbidden **from doing** X* has any more implication that you *have done X / are doing X* than being *forbidden **to do** X*. It may not be relevant, but interestingly, NGrams says the three most common words after *were forbidden from* are ***entering, using, going***, and the top three after *were forbidden to* are ***enter, go, use***. I suppose it's *possible* those are the three most likely things people have already done before being forbidden, ***and*** when they've never actually done it anyway. But I don't recognize the distinction as having any currency.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is  your opinion and you are entitled to it.

Comment: It's a well-known feature of English that [use of gerunds](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=were+forbidden+from+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) has increased ***a lot*** over the past couple of centuries [compared to infinitives](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=were+forbidden+to+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3). There's no good reason to suppose that reflects some new *semantic* context arising. Or that the new form split off just *part* of the old one's original scope.

Comment: @FumbleFingers For me, I like to eat chocolate and I like eating chocolate are not the 100% same thing. Who said anything about semantics? It's a structural thing, not semantics.

Comment: I think people [who like to eat meat and who like eating meat](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=like+to+eat+meat%2Clike+eating+meat&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) are probably just the same people on different days of the week! They're not even "distinct linguistic communities".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I like to eat meat. sets up a relationship between I like and eat meat. But I like eating meat. is the activity. You don't have to agree.

Comment: In the end I've downvoted this. Not because I disagree with your semantic distinction (which I still do), but because it seems you've somehow given the OP the mistaken impression *They forbade her going up onto her roof* is invalid without ***from***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Nope: This one and the from one implies [whatever]. Nothing about invalid at all. I even listed it: they forbade her going up on the roof. No from at all in that one.

Comment: Perhaps you should explicitly point out in the answer text that ***from*** is *optional* before the gerund. The OP seems / seemed not to understand that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I said both. That's enough. It shows that you don't have to use it.